# Is it possible to define the type of a parameter as enum values?

Tags: php, enums, signature

In the parameters of a function, is it possible to specify some enumerated values?

For example, instead of this:

```php
public function getValuesFromType(string $type) { /*...*/ }
```

I want to only allow some specific values - something like this pseudocode:

```php
public function getValuesFromType('a'||'b' $type) { /*...*/ }
```

I tried to create an Enum object containing the values, and add the Enum in the type. But when the function `getValuesFromType('a')` is run, an error says that `argument 1 must be of type MyTypeEnum, string given`...

```php
public function getValuesFromType(MyTypeEnum $type)
```

How can I limit the values that can be passed as parameters to this method?

Comment: You can't just try throwing random PHP code into the middle of a method signature and expect it to work. Just try and get the value from the enum using the string passed. If it doesn't exist, throw an exception.

Answer (score 6):

Oh boi, I'm a huge fan of Enum.

Let's use the following enum as example:

```php
enum MyTypeEnum
{
    case APPLE = 'apple';
    case BANANA = 'banana';
}
```

If you know you will have the instance of MyTypeEnum, you can use it as typehint:

```php
public function getValuesFromType(MyTypeEnum $type)
```

So you can use MyTypeEnum instance as parameter:

```php
$this->getValuesFromType(MyTypeEnum::APPLE)
```

But if you don't know what will be you param, then typehint as `string` and use `from()` or `tryFrom()` static function on MyTypeEnum.

```php
public function getValuesFromType(string $type) {
    $myType = MyTypeEnum::tryFrom($type);

    if (!$myType) {
       // handle null state
    }

    // $myType is a valid MyTypeEnum instance
}
```

`from()` will throw and exception if the value is not matching with any case, `tryFrom()` will simply return `null`

But there is a third way, that I like to use:

If you add a function to your enum, you can call it on an instance:

```php
enum MyTypeEnum
{
    case APPLE = 'apple';
    case BANANA = 'banana';

    public function values() {
        return match($this) {
            self::APPLE => ['red', 'green'],
            self::BANANA => ['yellow', 'brown']
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```php
MyTypeEnum::tryFrom('apple')?->values() // return ['red', 'green']
MyTypeEnum::tryFrom('orange')?->values() // return null
MyTypeEnum::tryFrom('orange')?->values() ?? [] // return []
```

---

If you need union types, you need a single `|` char.

`public function getValuesFromType(string|array $type)`

But you cannot use `'a' | 'b'`, or `MyTypeEnum::APPLE | MyTypeEnum::BANANA`. Type must be simple like `string $type` or complex instance like `MyTypeEnum $type`.

Answer (score 0):

- PHP 8.3
- Symfony 6.3

If you have this error : **Compile Error: Case CHOICE_ONE of non-backed enum App\Enum\EnumChoice must not have a value**, make sure your enum looks like this (adding the *string* type) :

```
<?php

namespace App\Enum;

enum EnumChoice:string {
    case CHOICE_ONE = 'ONE';
    case CHOICE_TWO = 'TWO';
}
```